# add a library to silex

Tags: php, silex

I know this question has already been asked, but it seems that autoloading process changed a little bit with composer.

I just want to add a class library to my silex project.

So I made this file:
vendor\lib\picture.php

```
<?php
namespace MyNamespace;

class Picture
{
    function testage()
    {
        echo 'hihaaa ça marche'; exit;
    }
}
```

in vendor/composer/autoload_namespaces.php, I added this line to the big array:

```
'MyNamespace' => $vendorDir . '/lib/',
```

And in the main file I added:

```
use MyNamespace\Picture as Picture;
```

and called it like that:

```
$app->register(new Picture());
```

which gives me this error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'MyNamespace\Picture' not found...
```

I just don't know how to add a class that I can use from any controller, easily, without command line (I don't use composer, I downloaded silex preconfigured), any idea?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you're using composer you should not change the vendor directory. You should not add files into it, and you should not modify the composer-generated files.

I recommend you put those classes into the `src` directory. @gunnx shows how you can configure autoloading in `composer.json`, so that it gets re-generated every time you run `composer install`.

The file would be in `src/MyNamespace/Picture.php`. The autoload config in `composer.json` would be:

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": { "MyNamespace": "src/" }
    }
}
```

The actual solution is a combination of the two previous answers. But I think it's important to get the details right ;-).

Comment: At the end of his question he explicitly says he's not using composer.

Comment: Thx @igorw! Putting "src/" made it work for me! =) (Though i wonder why)

Answer (score 2):

Your Picture class should be in this file: `vendor/lib/MyNamespace/Picture.php`. Note the full namespace and the casing.

Comment: thank you, your answer is really helping. I also add to implement the ServiceProviderInterface and add the boot and register methods, and now I have no error.

Answer (score 2):

You can add your own code to the autoloader by adding the following to your composer.json
e.g.

```
{
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": {"Acme": "src/"}
}
```